# how can I use a variable as an array name in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, variables

I am currently working on a script that receives input from stdin, and then loads the input line by line into an array for further processing. Although the array works fine if I set the array name directly, I cannot get the array part to work properly when I attempt to use a variable as the array name, the code itself is below:

```
input=$(</dev/stdin)
# back up the field separator for later
OLDIFS=$IFS
# set the field separator to newline
IFS=$'\n'
# populate an array from that variable, as delimited by the IFS
lines=($input)
```

and this is what I have tried for setting the array name as a variable

```
arrayname="something"
eval $arrayname=($input)
```

but unfortunately when I go to run this, I get the following error:

```
./f.sh: line 53: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./f.sh: line 53: `                      eval $arrayname=($input)'
```

having said all of this, I was wondering if anyone would know what I could do to make this work correctly? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of playing with `IFS`, which is useless in your case (even though I'm an avid fan of `IFS`, I tend to only use it when necessary!), there's a much better and much more efficient way of loading a file into an array. Incidentally, it is not very well-known: it's the command `mapfile` (type `help mapfile` in your terminal running bash for more info).

Hence,

```
mapfile lines
```

will read from standard input and store each line in an array `lines`. This also stores the trailing new line character, so if you want to trim it, use the `-t` option:

```
mapfile -t lines
```

To print out the array, one line per entry, use:

```
printf '%s\n' "${lines[@]}"
```

(observe the quoting for `"${lines[@]}"`).

Please note that using `eval` is evil!

Your main problem is to use a variable as an array name. bash doesn't have what is called a pointer in other languages. Without using `eval`, it will be difficult to use an array name stored in a variable (unless you use little trickeries). But, as I already said, `eval` is evil. Maybe you should spend a little more time thinking about your design, there's probably another (better?) way to achieve what you're trying to.

Comment: thanks for the info! after what you had mentioned with thinking about the design, I've thought of a way of not having to use a variable as a name for the array, although it would require that I append data onto an array instead, do you know if that would be possible? for instance I move one file into an array (say it contained 40 lines or so), after which I would add a second file onto the array

Comment: was able to figure it out, thanks again for your help though :)

Answer (score 1):

Use indirection:

```
men=(Jack John Joe)
women=(Zoe Zelda Zanna)
gender=women[@]
echo ${!gender}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
read -a arr
printf '%s\n' ${arr[@]}
```

Is it the solution ?